# Predict() on Keras gives alway different results even if the NN and the dataset is the same

Tags: python, keras

I have my model and a fixed dataset on which I do the train_test_split twice: once for getting train and test sets and the second time for getting a validation set too.

I have to reuse the same network, on the same data, twice in two different modules but every time I do that I get different results. 
Is there a way to fix it?

I have the weights fixed and `random_state = 42` so to eliminate every form of randomness but still it does not seem enough.

The optimizer I used is Adam and the loss function is the mean absolute error.

Comment: You need to include source code for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: Generally, Keras gets its source of randomness from the NumPy random number generator. Try setting `from numpy.random import seed; seed(42)` and see if you get reproducible results

Comment: Thanks, i've tried that but still on predict, sometimes, i obtain values that are not only diffent from the others but orribles too.

Answer (score 0):

Do you train and evaluate (predict) the model in the same script and process?

Please check the official guide how to [obtain reproducible results using keras during development](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-reproducible-results-using-keras-during-development).

In addition you can try to [save and load](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model) your model (in another file) to check the predictions.

Comment: Yes, I train and evaluate on the same process. Then i start a new process with the same nn and sets but I get different results

Comment: Can you post the relavant parts of your source code to reproduce this manner?

Comment: I managed to solve the problem, I had to set the seed both for numpy and tensorflow which is my backend. Then in worked.